# Imagenes en ItexSharp

Tags: c#, itextsharp

Estoy trabajando con `Chart` en `C#` donde hago la graficación de datos y cuando el usuario da *click* en le botón reporte se crea el reporte *pdf* de `ItexSharp`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Hasta ahi voy bien pero quisiera que la hiciera un poco más grande sin distorsionarse, que abarque lo ancho y un poco más largo de la hoja. Este es el código que le puse para que la imagen creciera pero no funciona como yo quisera:

```
chart_imagen.ScalePercent(100f,100f);
chart_imagen.ScaleAbsolute(500f, 500f);
```

Y además quisiera que la numeración del *eje X* fuera de 1 en 1 hasta el número que decida el usuario. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Como estas generando el chart?, ¿con que complemento o como?, ¿Podrías mostrar el código ?

Comment: Hola am con las series del chart

Comment: Si, pero que control es el chart? el que viene por default?, el proyecto es web? wpf? windows??

Comment: es de windows y si es el q viene por default

Comment: Puedes mostrar el código? de cuando generas el PDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hice un ejemplo te anexo el proyecto y parte del código:

La interfaz quedo así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el form:

```
 public Form1()
    {
        try
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CrearGrafica();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            CrearPDF();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    public class CambiosPrecios {
        public DateTime fecha { get; set; }
        public int idProducto { get; set; }
        public string nombreProducto { get; set; }
        public decimal precio { get; set; }
    }

    private void CrearGrafica()
    {
        try
        {
            //Lleno el objeto de CambiosPrecios
            var cambiosPrecios = new List<CambiosPrecios>();
            cambiosPrecios.Add(new CambiosPrecios { fecha = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1),idProducto = 1,  nombreProducto = "Producto 1", precio = 12.30M });
            cambiosPrecios.Add(new CambiosPrecios { fecha = new DateTime(2016, 2, 1),idProducto = 1,  nombreProducto = "Producto 1", precio = 15.30M });
            cambiosPrecios.Add(new CambiosPrecios { fecha = new DateTime(2016, 3, 1),idProducto = 1,  nombreProducto = "Producto 1", precio = 14.60M });
            cambiosPrecios.Add(new CambiosPrecios { fecha = new DateTime(2016, 4, 1),idProducto = 1,  nombreProducto = "Producto 1", precio = 12.90M });
            cambiosPrecios.Add(new CambiosPrecios { fecha = new DateTime(2016, 5, 1),idProducto = 1,  nombreProducto = "Producto 1", precio = 12.90M });
            cambiosPrecios.Add(new CambiosPrecios { fecha = new DateTime(2016, 6, 1),idProducto = 1,  nombreProducto = "Producto 1", precio = 12.90M });
            cambiosPrecios.Add(new CambiosPrecios { fecha = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1), idProducto = 2, nombreProducto = "Producto 2", precio = 18.30M });
            cambiosPrecios.Add(new CambiosPrecios { fecha = new DateTime(2016, 2, 1), idProducto = 2, nombreProducto = "Producto 2", precio = 19.30M });
            cambiosPrecios.Add(new CambiosPrecios { fecha = new DateTime(2016, 3, 1), idProducto = 2, nombreProducto = "Producto 2", precio = 30.60M });
            cambiosPrecios.Add(new CambiosPrecios { fecha = new DateTime(2016, 4, 1), idProducto = 2, nombreProducto = "Producto 2", precio = 28.90M });
            cambiosPrecios.Add(new CambiosPrecios { fecha = new DateTime(2016, 5, 1), idProducto = 2, nombreProducto = "Producto 2", precio = 25.90M });
            cambiosPrecios.Add(new CambiosPrecios { fecha = new DateTime(2016, 6, 1), idProducto = 2, nombreProducto = "Producto 2", precio = 30.90M });
            cambiosPrecios.Add(new CambiosPrecios { fecha = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1), idProducto = 3, nombreProducto = "Producto 3", precio = 13.50M });
            cambiosPrecios.Add(new CambiosPrecios { fecha = new DateTime(2016, 2, 1), idProducto = 3, nombreProducto = "Producto 3", precio = 13.55M });
            cambiosPrecios.Add(new CambiosPrecios { fecha = new DateTime(2016, 3, 1), idProducto = 3, nombreProducto = "Producto 3", precio = 14.30M });
            cambiosPrecios.Add(new CambiosPrecios { fecha = new DateTime(2016, 4, 1), idProducto = 3, nombreProducto = "Producto 3", precio = 14.30M });
            cambiosPrecios.Add(new CambiosPrecios { fecha = new DateTime(2016, 5, 1), idProducto = 3, nombreProducto = "Producto 3", precio = 14.30M });
            cambiosPrecios.Add(new CambiosPrecios { fecha = new DateTime(2016, 6, 1), idProducto = 3, nombreProducto = "Producto 3", precio = 14.30M });
            cambiosPrecios.Add(new CambiosPrecios { fecha = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1), idProducto = 4, nombreProducto = "Producto 4", precio = 11.00M });
            cambiosPrecios.Add(new CambiosPrecios { fecha = new DateTime(2016, 2, 1), idProducto = 4, nombreProducto = "Producto 4", precio = 12.00M });
            cambiosPrecios.Add(new CambiosPrecios { fecha = new DateTime(2016, 3, 1), idProducto = 4, nombreProducto = "Producto 4", precio = 13.00M });
            cambiosPrecios.Add(new CambiosPrecios { fecha = new DateTime(2016, 4, 1), idProducto = 4, nombreProducto = "Producto 4", precio = 25.00M });
            cambiosPrecios.Add(new CambiosPrecios { fecha = new DateTime(2016, 5, 1), idProducto = 4, nombreProducto = "Producto 4", precio = 25.90M });
            cambiosPrecios.Add(new CambiosPrecios { fecha = new DateTime(2016, 6, 1), idProducto = 4, nombreProducto = "Producto 4", precio = 15.90M });
            //Fin - Lleno el objeto de CambiosPrecios

            var titulo = new Title("Cambio de precios(2016)",Docking.Top,new System.Drawing.Font("Verdana",14.0f),System.Drawing.Color.BlueViolet );
            chart1.Titles.Add(titulo);
            chart1.DataSource = cambiosPrecios;

            //Titulo de la X
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].Axes[0].Title = "Mes";
            //Titulo de la Y
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].Axes[1].Title = "$ Precio";

            //Cambiar el intevalo de 1 en  1 para el eje Y
            Axis xaxis = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;
            xaxis.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Auto;
            xaxis.Interval = 2;//Numero de intervalo

            var productos = (from x in cambiosPrecios select x.nombreProducto).Distinct();//Selecciono todos los productos distintos, seran las SERIES en el chart
            foreach (var s in productos)
            {
                List<string> xvals = new List<string>();
                List<decimal> yvals = new List<decimal>();
                string serieName = s;
                chart1.Series.Add(serieName);
                //Grafica lineal
                chart1.Series[serieName].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;

                foreach (var v in cambiosPrecios)
                {
                    try
                    {

                        if (String.Equals(serieName, v.nombreProducto.ToString(), StringComparison.Ordinal))
                        {
                            yvals.Add(v.precio);
                            xvals.Add(v.fecha.ToString("MMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                        throw new InvalidOperationException(ex.ToString());
                    }
                }
                try
                {
                    chart1.Series[serieName].XValueType = ChartValueType.Auto;
                    chart1.Series[serieName].YValueType = ChartValueType.Auto;
                    chart1.Series[serieName].Points.DataBindXY( xvals.ToArray(), yvals.ToArray());
                    ////Muestre el valor en le punto 
                    //foreach (var p in chart1.Series[serieName].Points) {
                    //    p.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
                    //}
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    throw new InvalidOperationException(ex.ToString());
                }


            }

            chart1.DataBind();
            chart1.Visible = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.ToString(), ex);
        }
    }

    private void CrearPDF() {
        try
        {
            Document Doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER.Rotate(), 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);//Horizontal
            //Document Doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc
                , new System.IO.FileStream(
                    System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() 
                    + "\\EjemploGraficas" + Guid.NewGuid() + ".pdf",
                    System.IO.FileMode.Create));

            Doc.Open();

            // Le colocamos el título y el autor
            // **Nota: Esto no será visible en el documento
            Doc.AddTitle("Reporte de ejemplo CHART");
            Doc.AddCreator("Cristina Carrasco - cristina.carrasco.angulo@gmail.com");

            //Titulo del documento
            var parrafo = new Paragraph("Titulo del PDF");
            parrafo.SpacingBefore = 20;
            parrafo.SpacingAfter = 20;
            parrafo.Alignment = 1; //0-Left, 1 middle,2 Right
            Doc.Add(parrafo);
            Doc.Add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

            //Agrego la Gráfica
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                chart1.SaveImage(memoryStream, System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartImageFormat.Bmp);
                iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(memoryStream.GetBuffer());
                img.ScalePercent(120f);
                //img.ScaleAbsolute(500f, 300f);

                Doc.Add(img);


            }
            Doc.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.ToString(),ex);
        }
    }
```

Tu pregunta sobre el intervalo se arregla con este código:

```
//Cambiar el intevalo de 1 en  1 para el eje X
Axis xaxis = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
xaxis.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Auto;
xaxis.Interval = 1;//Numero de intervalo
```

Para el eje Y:

```
//Cambiar el intevalo de 1 en  1 para el eje Y
Axis xaxis = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;
xaxis.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Auto;
xaxis.Interval = 1;//Numero de intervalo
```

El proyecto lo puedes descargar de esta liga:
[Proyecto de ejemplo Chart en c# Imprimir a PDF itextSharp](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1NrUmB-KIz6VVJNelBHLXgwTFE/view?usp=sharing)

El PDF generado quedo de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que te sea de ayuda, saludos.

Comment: ey Cristina muchas gracias es lo que buscaba ;)

Comment: @karol me da gusto haber podido ayudarte. :-)